# Linq one Result from multiple Lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have one method that calculates a score. simplified:

```
public static int GetScore(int v1, int v2, char v3)
{
    //calculate score 
    return score;
}
```

`v1`, `v2` and `v3` are 3 values from 3 lists:

```
List<int> Values1 = new List<int>();
List<int> Values2 = new List<int>();
List<char> Values3 = new List<char>();
//fill Values1, Values 2, Values3
```

How must be the `Select` to determine each combination of the three lists and determine the highest score? I thought of something like that:

```
int MaxScore = Values1.Select(x => Values2.Select(y => GetScore(x, y))).Max(); // ???
```

My current approach

```
int MaxScore = 0;
foreach (int x in Values1)
{
    foreach (int y in Values2)
    {
        foreach (char z in Values3)
        {
            int Score = GetScore(x, y, z);
            if (Score > MaxScore)
            {
                MaxScore = Score;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to measure by same index? measure the highest score in general among all three lists?
please detail your case

Comment: All you need is a method that produces an enumerable that is all possible combinations of the values in the lists, and then do a simple `Select` followed by `Max`. Write that method - figure out the algorithm (hint: nested loops might work well) and `yield` the possible combinations.

Comment: Try `int MaxScore = Values1.SelectMany(x => Values2.SelectMany(y => Values3.Select(z => GetScore(x, y, z)))).Max();`.

Comment: @Byyo - It is exactly the same answer as Maarten's. I think you should just go with his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion in my comment, you can do this:

```
int MaxScore =
    Values1
        .SelectMany(x =>
            Values2
                .SelectMany(y =>
                    Values3
                        .Select(z =>
                            GetScore(x, y, z))))
        .Max();
```

Answer (score 6):

In this case I think LINQ Query syntax is more clear.

```
var data = from v1 in Values1
           from v2 in Values2
           from v3 in Values3
           select GetScore(v1, v2, v3);
var max = data.Max();
```